# Why doesn't HIV spread through vectors?

Tags: virology, hiv

HIV spreads only through body fluids. If a mosquito bites an HIV infected individual and then an uninfected individual, will the virus spread  to the new individual?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This doesn't take much effort to answer!  Googling "HIV mosquito" brings us straight to [this blog post](https://www.nature.com/scitable/blog/viruses101/why_cant_mosquitos_transmit_hiv), which gives three main reasons (along with more details, links to other resources, etc.):

> Only saliva is injected into humans when a mosquito bites and thus HIV positive blood that a mosquito may have previously ingested is never transmitted to other humans.
>
> Unlike mosquito borne diseases, HIV is unable to replicate within the mosquito's gut and therefore is broken down.
>
> HIV circulates in human blood at a far lower level than would be necessary to create a new infection.